# Creating variables dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, loops, for-loop

I'm working on a REST styled API, and I want to be able to break the URL down into individual variables.

Say I have the following URL: www.example.com/user/post/1

I'd like to make the following variables:

```
$uri_1 = user
$uri_2 = post
$uri_3 = 1
```

I tried to do this but it got stuck in a loop

```
 $path = explode('/', $this->path($uri));
 for($i=0;$i < count($path);$i++){
       $uri_.$i = $path[i];
 }
```

Comment: Why do you need separate variables, why not just use the array returned by `explode`?

Comment: @Barmar This is within my API. It's part of the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$url = explode('/', strtolower(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')));

$uri_1 = isset($url[0])?$url[0]:'';
$uri_2 = isset($url[1])?$url[1]:'';
$uri_3 = isset($url[2])?$url[2]:'';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I wanted to avoid a bunch of if statements, so this is short and concise too. Thanks

Comment: @R.S. I understand. I simply needed to separate the URL into individual components. The API will take care of filtering inputs.

Comment: @R.S - Duh! It works with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which returns the pathname. Using it with an url where the domainname is included, and trying to replace the `$_SERVER` variable with such a string, won't work, like `http://www.google.com/i/didnt/getit/`. As long as it uses the actual URL in the `$_SERVER` variable, and you don't try to replace that with a string, it will work just fine!

Comment: If the url in your browser address bar is example.com/user/post/1/?q=1 ... $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] will return 'user/post/1/?q=1'

Comment: You're right the above example would work... but if the url is change to example.com/user/post/?q=1 ..then $uri_3 = ?q=1

Comment: Well yes, then that would be the third part of the URL, but since the OP does'nt mention querystrings, let's assume it works the way he wanted it to, and I use this all the time in my home made PHP controller for smaller sites with no problems what so ever!

Comment: @R.S. I can filter the inputs. If I decide I don't want the character "a" to appear in anything, I can filter for that. I'm not worried about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it for an arbitrary number of variables, using PHP's variable variables feature:

```
 $path = explode('/', $this->path($uri));
 for($i=0;$i < count($path);$i++){
       ${"uri_".$i} = $path[i];
 }
```

Comment: Barmar, this is exactly what I was looking for. I already accepted adaneo's answer because it works and it's simple, but this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you.